# SSRS adding a percentage column which gives a percentage of the total

Tags: reporting-services

I have an issue with SSRS I hope is really simple to solve.  What I have is a matrix which currently looks a bit like this:

[Just numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03XQA.png)

There is a parent row group applied grouping them numbers according to item.

What I'm hoping to do is add a column to the right giving the percentage of the total applied to each item.  So the output I'm hoping for looks something like this:

[Numbers and percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywttu.png)

I'm just not sure how to get to this point although it seems like it should be pretty simple.  I have tried putting an expression in saying something like:

```
=100*IIF(Sum(Fields!count_b.Value)=0, 0, Fields!count_b.Value/sum(Fields!count_b.Value))
```

But it doesn't produce the desired result because the 'sum' part is grouped according to the row group.

Apologies if I'm being incredibly dense...!

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Edit : format code

Comment: Never mind I have arrived at an answer! For anyone reading this who is also wondering, I tried:       `**=100*IIF(sum(Fields!count_b.Value, "dataset")=0, 0, Sum(Fields!count_b.Value)/sum(Fields!count_b.Value.Value, "dataset"))**`

Comment: Mark the question as answered with the answer if it has resolved the issue for you - that way it can help people in the future if they have the same question.

Comment: Hi BishNaboB - I've answered the question below, it won't let me accept my own answer though (for 2 days).  Hope this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind I have arrived at an answer! For anyone reading this who is also wondering, I tried: `=100*IIF(sum(Fields!count_b.Value, "dataset")=0, 0, Sum(Fields!count_b.Value)/sum(Fields!count_b.Value.Value, "dataset"))` - this solved my problem.